# LTspice (XVII) Use user defined parameter in component instance name and net name

Tags: ltspice

I'm trying to simulate a lumped transmission line using the bussed wire and array component notation:
[image]

For a hardcoded array length everything works fine but I want to control the number of lumped segments using a parameter which unfortunately doesn't work, neither for component names nor for net names. In net names without colon notation, LTspice doesn't even allow curly braces.

When hardcoding the length into the component name, the message window (appears when changing the name) says:
[image]

Is there a workaround to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It can't be done. BTW, the way you've wired the elements means you'll just have N elements in parallel. If you want cascaded cells, you have to use [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1f4l.png).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Could you elaborate a little on the second part of your answer? I wired the elements according to [this image](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/ltspice-begginer/?action=dlattach;attach=315169;image). I've simulated [your and their circuit](https://imgur.com/3p13s5Q) and the results are pretty [the same](https://imgur.com/XGt5Fbi)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the bus taps. You can discard what I said, or consider it an alternative way. At any rate, it can't be done. You have to specify manually everything.